# Why this code is not printing 30, since int is primitive and mutable?

Tags: java

```
package com.test;

public class Person {

    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}


package com.test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.setAge(10);

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.setAge(person1.getAge());

        person1.setAge(30);

        System.out.println(person2.getAge());

    }
}
```

I thought that this will print 30, since int is primitive and mutable.

Can someone please explain me why?

I am not accidentally printing person2 here. I need to understand the real concept behind the same.

Now I am checking the same with wrapper now. But result is the same .

```
package com.test;

public class Person {

    private Integer age;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

Even tried the same with a mutable Date class :

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Date;

public class Person {

    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}


package com.test;

import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.setDate(new Date(2015, 3, 8));

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.setDate(person1.getDate());

        System.out.println("Person2 date before modifying " + person2.getDate());

        person1.setDate(new Date(2015, 3, 9));

        System.out.println("Person2 date after modifying " + person2.getDate());

    }
}
```

This prints :

> Person2 date before modifying Thu Apr 08 00:00:00 IST 3915
>  Person2
>   date after modifying Thu Apr 08 00:00:00 IST 3915

Comment: May want to google java pass by reference vs pass by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why this code is not printing 30

Because you're outputting the `age` field of `person2`, which you never set to 30. You're setting the `age` field of **`person1`** to `30`, but not `person2`. Instance fields are instance-specific.

In particular, if you were expecting this line to create some link between the instances:

```
person2.setAge(person1.getAge());
```

it doesn't. It gets the *value* of teh `age` field of `person1` and then assigns that *value* (`10`, at that point) to the `age` field of `person2`. There is no ongoing link between them.

Blow-by-blow account:

```
Person person1 = new Person();        // Creates a Person instance
person1.setAge(10);                   // Sets person1's age to 10

Person person2 = new Person();        // Creates a separate Person instance
person2.setAge(person1.getAge());     // Sets person2's age to 10

person1.setAge(30);                   // Sets person1's age to 30; no effect on person2

System.out.println(person2.getAge()); // Shows person2's age (10)
```

> ...since int is primitive and mutable?

`int` is primitive; you could argue that it's **not** mutable, if you take mutable to mean what it normally means: Having state that can change. `int`s don't have that. `5` is `5` is `5` and cannot change. Variables *containing* `int` values can be updated to contain *different* `int` values, but that's changing the variable, not the `int`.

In contrast, objects have state that can change without changing the variable that refers to them:

```
// Create a LinkedList and save a reference to it in `list`
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

// Change the state of the list
list.add("Foo");
```

In the second statement above, the *variable* `list` isn't changed; it still contains a reference to the same list. That statement changes the state of the list (not the state of the variable referring to it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder why people suddenly downVoted the same.So this has got nothing to do with object reference ?? I am confused!! can you please explain a little more.

Comment: @Valath: Confused about what?

Comment: I was thinking the same way as the below answer. So that is wrong right?
Since Integer is immutable, i think this is giving 10. If it has been a Date, a mutable object will it behave the other way around?

Comment: @Valath: If you used a mutable object and changed its state, rather than changing the content of the variable pointing at it, you'd see the effect regardless of which reference you used. But not if you did what you did above, assigning a **new** value to the variable. E.g., look at my `list` example above. If I did `list = new LinkedList<String>();` on the second line, then I'd be changing the variable, not the state of the object it referred to.

Comment: Even I tried with mutable Date now. It is also working as you said. So am thinking that each object has different memory location in heap. Modifying other one without invoking setter will not modify the interrelated values, just like mine. Is there any chance to get into a situation like I explained above in java?

Comment: @Valath: Different objects live in different parts of memory, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not print 30 precisely because `int` is a primitive type, rather than an Object / Reference data type such as `Integer`.
This results in each Person object instance containing its own age value, and these values are not shared.
Your code would print 30 if age was defined as an `Integer` rather than an `int` (as well as the `setAge` method argument):

```
public class Person {

    private Integer age;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to rethink here. This is not gonna work. Please see discussions on the above answer.

Comment: I am fairly sure that it IS going to work. You don't seem to have a proper grasp on the difference between primitive types and object types... `Integer` is a class that "encapsulates" an int, so it can be treated just like `List<String>` in T.J. Crowder's answer